# Required imports for Meteor

Tags: meteor

In meteor project, do I need to import `{Meteor}`,`{Mongo}`, and`{check}` in this example?  Why?

**collections.js**

```
    // import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo' // ---- i have to import this?

    Bookmarks = new Mongo.Collection('bookmarks')
```

**methods.js**

```
    // import {check} from 'meteor/check' // ---- i have to import this?
    import {Bookmarks} from "/imports/schema/bookmarks/index"

    Meteor.methods({
     'bookmark.add'({name, url}){
      check(name,String) // ---------------
      check(url,String)

    const bookmarkId = Bookmarks.insert({name,url})
    Meteor.isServer && console.log(`Id ${bookmarkId} inserted`)
  },
  'bookmark.remove'(_id){
    check(_id,String)

    const bookmark = Bookmarks.findOne({_id})
    if (!bookmark){
      Meteor.isServer && console.log('no such a bookmark!')
    } else {
      const removeBookmarkId = Bookmarks.remove({_id})
      Meteor.isServer && console.log(`remove result ${removeBookmarkId?'success':'error'}`)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**.  Meteor makes heavy use of the module system for imports and exports.  You can read more about how Meteor modules works, and the reasons motivating the move to Meteor modules [here](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/modules.html).